# Using telnet to get website header

Tags: http, telnet

I have question, is it possible to get header of website by using telnet? Website looks like this `domain.name.server.com/~USER` (just example). And I want to get it header by telnet.

`telnet domain.name.server.com/~USER 80` <-- doesn't work

`telnet domain.name.server.com 80` works but I neet to get ~user. Is there any possibility to do this?

Answer (score 18):

Use `telnet domain.name.server.com 80` then

```
HEAD /~USER HTTP/1.1
Host: domain.name.server.com
```

*(Then you have to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> once more.)*

Now it should show you the header of this page.

For a real life example:

```
$ telnet unix.stackexchange.com 80                 
Trying 198.252.206.16...
Connected to unix.stackexchange.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
HEAD /questions/237635/using-telnet-to-get-website-header HTTP/1.1
Host: unix.stackexchange.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, no-cache="Set-Cookie", max-age=60
Content-Length: 70679
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 19:27:43 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 19:26:43 GMT
Vary: *
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Guid: dbf9d0f6-0ca4-423f-98f0-4cdf2bf51bf1
Set-Cookie: prov=08886524-c640-40ad-a0ee-246db3219228; domain=.stackexchange.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Date: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 19:26:43 GMT

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: If you don't have `telnet`, you can get the same sort of thing using `nc` or `netcat` (distros vary in what they call it, and there's an original and GNU version in use).

Comment: You should also include `Host: unix.stackexchange.com` so that the server knows which website you want, when it serves multiple sites as _virtual hosts_.

Comment: Why oh why are you using HTTP/1.0 here? Current (and what makes any reasonable use of the `Host:` header) is HTTP/1.1, the major feature of which was name-based virtual hosts.

Comment: If you care to help out the world just a bit, you could use TLS, too. `gnutls-cli $host -p $port` or `openssl s_client -connect $host:$port`, then type out the HTTP headers as normal.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use `wget` instead of telnet, you can get the headers all with one command:

```
wget -q -S -O - domain.name.server.com/~USER | : 2>&1
```

- `-q` turns off normal log messaging
- `-S` turns on logging of headers from the server
- `-O -` directs the content of the downloaded file to STDOUT
- `| :` pipes the content of the downloaded file to the no-op utility `:`.  This effectively prevents downloading the whole file, which is advantageous if it is a large file
- `2>&1` (optional) redirects the logged headers to STDOUT

For example:

```
$ wget -q -S -O - unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237635/using-telnet-to-get-website-header | :
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Cache-Control: public, no-cache="Set-Cookie", max-age=49
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  Expires: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 21:22:21 GMT
  Last-Modified: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 21:21:21 GMT
  Vary: *
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  X-Request-Guid: 5ac03697-68fa-4be5-9f32-2905ec3eff38
  Set-Cookie: prov=5d9866f4-9d98-4587-a7cc-f6ea5cd76075; domain=.stackexchange.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
  Date: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 21:21:32 GMT
  Content-Length: 76585
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Curl is a succinct way to view HTTP headers also:

```
curl -v http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237635/using-telnet-to-get-website-header
```

Comment: Welcome (?) to Unix & Linux!  You have posted the above as an answer, but it does not really answer the question (“is it possible to get the header of a website ***by using telnet?***”).  Helpful hints should be done in comments, for which you need a little more [reputation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score -1):

You can also do this over https, using openssl instead of telnet. There is an example in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZR26On6h6g&t=4s) that I recently published:

```
openssl s_client -connect domain.name.server.com:443
HEAD /~USER HTTP/1.0
Host: domain.name.server
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/209189)

Comment: @SatōKatsura Well, technically, “You can also do this over https, using openssh instead of telnet” does look like an attempt at an answer. But it's completely wrong: ssh has nothing to do with https, and anyway an http website would not respond over https.

Comment: Yes, but the answer becomes correct with `openssl` instead of `openssh`, which is what the linked tutorial says (provided, of course, the site also supports https).  It could be a honest typo...

Comment: The (currently most recent) comment by [Blacklight Shining](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/20714/blacklight-shining) on the answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/237648/100397 offers a solution using OpenSSL.- `openssl s_client -connect $host:$port`. I've added that in here, since it's pretty much what the YouTube video does, but more d r a w n - o u t.